# break в цикле do while

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, имею цикл do { } while (); как сделать такое правило, если счетчик $i == 10 то цикл останавливается?

Comment: Ваш вопрос - 1000-й с меткой PHP :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
   do {
      if (есть фото) {
         ваши действия
         $i++;
      } else continue;
   } while ($i<=10);
}
```

как-то так, если я вас правильно понял. Но все же мне кажется вам лучше почистить базу отдельным скриптом на наличие фоток, и если их нет, то потереть в таблице. Тогда все гораздо проще будет

Comment: у меня while занят уже  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res));

Comment: а вам религия запрещает использовать его 2-й раз? :)
Опишите что вы вообще делаете. Может do while вам вообще не нужен.

Comment: я вывожу в цикле товары, нужно вывести 10 товаров не используя в sql Limit 10 , так как внутри цикла идет проверка товара на наличие картинки, и получается если стоит Limit 10 то из них он отбирает товары 3-4 с битыми картинками, и выводятся всего 6-7 товарв. а мне надо строго 10 товаров с не битыми картинками. как использовать эту религию на второй раз)?

Comment: а почему бы вам не выбирать sql запросом только те, у которых есть фото?

Comment: Дело в том что, фото там есть у всех, а наличие этой фотографии бывает и нету)  
нужно просто к этому while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2));  
добавить $i++<=10, как сделать правильно?

Comment: Все сделал.

Comment: Обновил ответ! Лучше бы вам все-таки почистить базу, и делать затем запрос с LIMIT 10, поверьте, так будет проще. К тому же почистить - написать скрипт - дело 5 минут, а выигрыш вдальнейшем будет существенный

Answer (score 0):

Вообще у вас в вопросе содержится ответ и зачем еще один цикл - непонятно.

```
$i = 0;
do {
  $i++;
  if ($i >= 10) break;
  /* код */
  } while (/* условие */);
```